# Example on matching direct children of the parent node in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I am trying to match direct children of a parent node in cytoscape.js. I want to make the child nodes of a parent node visible on clicking on it. There is simple selector to do this as per the Cytoscape JS docs- [Selector-Compound Nodes](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#selectors/compound-nodes)

This is what I am trying:

```
cy.$('node.master').click(function(){
   cy.$('node > this').css({visibility:'hidden',})
});
```

But I get the following in the console log - "The selector `node > this` is invalid ".

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not a valid token for selectors.  Use `node > node`.